# Are there any counter words that some native Koreans might not know?

Tags: vocabulary

as well as 개 – 'things' in general - there are lots of specific counter words in Korean, e.g.

> 곡 – pieces of music 
>  명 – people 
>  장 – sheets of paper

In most cases, I think using 개 rather than the correct counter would be grammatically incorrect.

Are there any/many counter words that are sufficiently obscure that the average adult Korean speaker might not know them? Or do they represent a limited and fairly well-known set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- 고등어 한 손 - two mackerels
- 장작 한 가리 - twenty pieces of firewood, used for things tied together
- 새끼 한 고팽이 - one roll of rope, only used for rope
- 북어 한 쾌 - twenty dried pollacks, only used for dried pollacks
- 오징어 한 축 - ten squids, only used for squids